# Certain keys (arrows, page-up, page-down) not working in rdesktop-vrdp

Tags: keyboard, virtualbox, remote-desktop, remote-control

I start and stop my VM headless style.

Start

```
VBoxHeadless -s Windows -v on -e "TCP/Address=0.0.0.0" -e "TCP/Ports=3389"
```

Stop

```
VBoxManage  controlvm Windows poweroff
```

And I connect to it using the rdesktop protocol that VirtualBox natively supports.

```
rdesktop-vrdp localhost:3389
```

However after my kernel was forcefully upgraded for me today, I had to also upgrade my Virtualbox installation from `VirtualBox-4.1-4.1.8_75467_fedora16-1.i686.rpm` to `VirtualBox-4.2-4.2.6_82870_fedora16-1.i686.rpm` and after doing so, found myself unable to use arrow keys, control keys, page-up, page-down, etc, in my rdesktop-vrdp VM window.

So the problem is: control/alt/arrow/etc keys not working in rdesktop-vrdp.

Comment: Did you recompile kernel with vbox setup after upgrade? Do you have a kernel.devel (sources) installed?

Answer (score 5):

As it turns out, `rdesktop-vrdp` is bundled within the Virtualbox installation, so even though it was working before the upgrade, it has stopped working. That's not the right rdesktop tool anyways.

The right tool is available through the package manager

`yum install rdesktop`

**Solution: Stop using rdesktop-vrdp and start using rdesktop.**